# Multiple orientations for tabs in the same JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to set the orientation of specific tabs in the same JTabbedPane. Specifically, I would like all of my tabs to have the same tabPlacement at the top, but have one group be left to right oriented, and another group right to left. Is that possible to due with a JTabbedPane, or would I have to make a JSplitPane with buttons and manually change the panel?

Comment: Are you talking about the content of various tab sections, or the tab titles?  Any tab title can have right-to-left text, like `tabbedPane.addTab("שלום", tabContent);`, and should render properly without any special coding.  Or do you mean that you want some tabs shown on the top left, and some shown on the top right?

Comment: Some tabs on the top left, and some on the top right.

Comment: I don’t think JTabbedPane can do that.  You can simulate one yourself, though, using a CardLayout for the content, and a horizontal Box containing JToggleButtons for the “tabs,” if you don’t mind that it won’t look exactly like a tabbed pane.